# Possible to have multiple OpenTelemetry Metrics Providers with different exporters?

Tags: c#, open-telemetry

Is it possible (in ASP.NETcore 7) to have multiple OpenTelemetry Metrics Providers, where each provides different Meters and sends their respective metrics to different endpoints?

What I would like to get to (pseudo code):

```
services.AddOpenTelemetry()     
.WithMetrics(metricsBuilder =>
{
    metricsBuilder.SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("foobar"));
    metricsBuilder.AddMeter("Meters.Category1.*");
    metricsBuilder.AddGenevaMetricExporter(exporterOptions => { exporterOptions.ConnectionString = "myEndpoint1"; });
})
.WithMetrics(metricsBuilder =>
{
    metricsBuilder.SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("foobar"));
    metricsBuilder.AddMeter("Meters.Category2.*");
    metricsBuilder.AddGenevaMetricExporter(exporterOptions => { exporterOptions.ConnectionString = "myEndpoint2"; });
});
```

Using them later:

```
Meter MyMeter1 = new("Meters.Category1.MyMeter1");
var foo = MyMeter1.CreateHistogram<double>("Foo");


Meter MyMeter2 = new("Meters.Category2.MyMeter2");
var bar = MyMeter2.CreateHistogram<double>("Bar");
```

Is this possible or how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible using the `WithMetrics` extension method. The [doc comments](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/66a606229e57d25e2b80a856b9634e9f8f241737/src/OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting/OpenTelemetryBuilder.cs#L75) on the method reads:

> Note: This is safe to be called multiple times and by library authors.
> Each registered configuration action will be applied sequentially.

Instead, you would need to manually instantiate two separate `MetricProvider`s, like so:

```cs
var meterProvider1 = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .AddMeter("Meters.Category1.*")
    .AddGenevaMetricExporter(exporterOptions => { exporterOptions.ConnectionString = "myEndpoint1"; })
    .Build();
var meterProvider2 = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .AddMeter("Meters.Category2.*")
    .AddGenevaMetricExporter(exporterOptions => { exporterOptions.ConnectionString = "myEndpoint2"; })
    .Build();

Meter MyMeter1 = new Meter("Meters.Category1.MyMeter1");
var foo = MyMeter1.CreateHistogram<double>("Foo");

Meter MyMeter2 = new Meter("Meters.Category2.MyMeter2");
var bar = MyMeter2.CreateHistogram<double>("Bar");
```

However, there is a potential catch. The [doc comments](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry/Sdk.cs#L82) on `CreateMeterProviderBuilder` state:

> Creates a `MeterProviderBuilder` which is used to build
> a `MeterProvider`. In a typical application, a single
> `MeterProvider` is created at application startup and disposed
> at application shutdown. It is important to ensure that the provider is not
> disposed too early.

If you manually make two instances of `MeterProvider` you will need to figure out how to manage their lifecycle. The `WithMetrics` extension method does this by hooking in to the .NET dependency injection framework.

A quick solution is registering both `MeterProvider` instances as singletons, like so:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(meterProvider1);
services.AddSingleton(meterProvider2);
```

This should properly dispose of both instances when the application is terminated.

Comment: yeah I was thinking something along the same lines. I'll give this a try to see if metric submission works as expected

Comment: this seems to indeed work! thanks :)